# Python socket.send encoding

Tags: python, sockets, encoding

It seems i've run a problem with the encoding itself in where i need to pass Bing translation junks..

```
def _unicode_urlencode(params):
    if isinstance(params, dict):
        params = params.items()
    return urllib.urlencode([(k, isinstance(v, unicode) and v.encode('utf-8') or v) for k, v in params])

def _run_query(args):
        data = _unicode_urlencode(args)
        sock = urllib.urlopen(api_url + '?' + data)
        result = sock.read()
        if result.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8):
                result = result.lstrip(codecs.BOM_UTF8).decode('utf-8')
        elif result.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE):
                result = result.lstrip(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE).decode('utf-16-le')
        elif result.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE):
                result = result.lstrip(codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE).decode('utf-16-be')
        return json.loads(result)

def set_app_id(new_app_id):
        global app_id
        app_id = new_app_id

def translate(text, source, target, html=False):
        """
        action=opensearch
        """
        if not app_id:
                raise ValueError("AppId needs to be set by set_app_id")
        query_args = {
                'appId': app_id,
                'text': text,
                'from': source,
                'to': target,
                'contentType': 'text/plain' if not html else 'text/html',
                'category': 'general'
        }
        return _run_query(query_args)
...
text = translate(sys.argv[2], 'en', 'tr')
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 894
s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send("Bing translation: " + text.encode('utf8') + "\r");
s.close()
```

As you can see, if the translated text contains some turkish characters, the script fails to send the text to the socket..

Do you have any idea on how to get rid of this?

Regards.

Comment: did you try encoding the whole string? `text = "Bing translation: " + text + "\r"; s.send(text.encode('utf8');` also did you use text.decode('utf8') on the receiving  end.

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, what?

Comment: it didn't work. btw, receiving end is a server which created with c..

Comment: Also, which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.5.2.. UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128) or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is entirely unrelated to the socket. `text` is already a bytestring, and you're trying to encode it. What happens is that Python tries to converts the bytestring to a unicode via the safe ASCII encoding in order to be able to encode as UTF-8, and then fails because the bytestring contains non-ASCII characters.

You should fix `translate` to return a `unicode` object, by using a JSON variable that returns unicode objects.

Alternatively, if it is already encoding text encoded as UTF-8, you can simply use

```
s.send("Bing translation: " + text + "\r")
```

Comment: i added the translate code to the OP. I am not sure how to fix that. Can you explain it a bit more since i am newbie.. Thanks

Comment: @jamall55 The code you posted shows that most likely the JSON library is at fault. Since it is not in the standard library in 2.5 (you should really use a newer Python version, but I digress), which `json` library are you using here? And what don't you understand in this answer, i.e. what should I elaborate on?

Comment: i was able to get it done. It was all about encoding the string two times with the wrong one coming second. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

 text = u"text in you language"
 s.send(u"Bing translation: " + text.encode('utf8') + u"\r");
```

This must work. `text` must be spelled in utf-8 encoding.

Comment: didn't work out.
    s.send(u"CNN Bing translation: " + text.encode('utf8') + u"\r");
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: 1. what is your source file encoding?

Comment: -1 Apart from broken indentation in this answer, there is absolutely no reason why you would ever want to send unicode over a socket.

Comment: it's utf8. All i wanna do is send the translation junk that i got from bing through the socket..

Comment: it can't be. `u'your languge string'` is equal to `unicode('your language string', 'encoding of your source file')`. Then you might be wanting to convert it to some encoding, `ustr.encode('utf-8')`